# get options' value list of a select in an array or JSON without using loop or jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need options' value list in an array or JSON.
I have used following code.

```
var compArray=[];
jQuery("#myCombo option").each(function(){
       compArray.push(jQuery(this).val());
       });
```

But i dont want to iterate the options in a loop because my options list can grow.
I have used as

```
JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("myCombo").options)
```

But on stringify it shows empty JSON objects, though I can get value from

```
document.getElementById("myCombo").options[0].value
```

I have to pass these value in request parameter to server and I do not want to go through the looping.
Please suggest the optimized solution.

Comment: Are you sure this function is a bottleneck? I doubt you can do it without looping since `select.options[i]` is `HTMLOptionElement` which has references to its parent and such...
Just do not create jQuery instance for each option.
`Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("myCombo").options).map(function (item) {return item.value;})`

Comment: hi, i'm not sure of the impact of each function, but I have to manage overall performance. Looping will cost the performance, to the extant of unresponsive script error.

Comment: Wow. How many options have you got in select?

Comment: hi, its for product requirement, I am developing a product, in which user can design forms with any no of controls, show control count is the count of options in the select. So I'm helpless for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom serializer like this:

```
var options = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("sel").options),
    str = JSON.stringify(options, function(key, value){
       if(key === ""){
           return value;   
       }
       if(!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
          return value.value;   
       }
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vh9qD/

Or use iteration without creating jQuery instance for every option

```
var options = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("sel").options),
    str = JSON.stringify(options.map(function(item){return item.value;}));
```

Check this perf test: http://jsperf.com/get-options

Comment: hi it is not working in IE8, error thrown as follows. JScript Object expected.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support Array.prototype.map. You can use a shim https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It is showing script error on Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("sel").options).

Comment: thanks buddy, test 3 is showing better result in every browser, I'll use that one.

Answer (score 0):

`But i dont want to iterate the options in a loop because my options list can grow.`

This does not have anything to do with the combo.

Whenever you add/delete a `option` to the combo, just call a function, which will subsequently add/delete that `option` from your array.

```
function addDeleteListInArray( oVal, addDelete ) {
   if( addDelete ) {
       // add to array
       compArray.push( oVal );
   } else {
       // delete from array
       for( var i=0; i< compArray.length; i++ ) {
          if( compArray[ i ] == oVal ) {
              compArray.splice( i, 1 );
              break;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestion, but my option list is dynamic, options' order can be changed so on final submit only, i can iterate the options.

Comment: @sahihai - See my function. It accepts 2 parameters - `oVal` & `addDelete`. `addDelete` is a flag(0/1), which tells whether to add or delete. `oVal` is the value of the option that you add/delete. Call this every time you add/delete to/from your list.